# Cálculo da média móvel ponderada com ajuste exponencial

Tags: java, matemática

Como poderia calcular o `a` na seguinte fórmula em java:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz o seguinte : `Df = Df + a(1 -a) xx i`

Generalizei a formula só não sei como calcular o `a`, tipo fazer uma fórmula onde o `a = ...`

Esta fórmula é conhecida como média móvel ponderada com ajuste exponencial. Busquei em sites em ingles no google com a seguinte pesquisa : "exponential smoothing formula" mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Dt é uma sequência finita?

Comment: O que significa essas variáveis?

Comment: è uma sequencia temporal onde cada mês tem a sua quantidade vendida de um determinado produto.O a é o fator exponencial ou alfa Df é a quantidade em um determinado mês o i é um  exponencial. A formula funciona da seguinte maneira dado um alfa eu calculo a quantidade vendiva de um produto no mes seguinte. O que eu quero calcular agora é o alfa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olhando para a fórmula, acho que a solução seria isso:

```
public static double smooth(double a, double... d) {
    double soma = 0.0;
    double potencia = 1.0;
    for (int i = d.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        soma += a * potencia * d[i];
        potencia *= 1.0 - a;
    }
    return soma;
}
```

Realizei um teste:

```
System.out.println(smooth(0.05, 10, 40, 50, 20, 35));
```

Eis o resultado:

```
7.078253125000002
```

Já para achar o termo `a` (supondo que esteja entre 0.0 e 1.0), procuramos por meio de iterações, o máximo global da função, sabendo-se que não há máximos locais:

```
public static double bestSmooth(double... d) {
    double v1 = 0.0;
    double v5 = 1.0;
    while (true) {
        double v3 = (v1 + v5) / 2;
        if (v3 == v1 || v3 == v5) return v3;
        double s1 = smooth(v1, d);
        double s3 = smooth(v3, d);
        double s5 = smooth(v5, d);
        if (s5 >= s3 && s5 >= s1) {
            v1 = v3;
        } else if (s1 >= s3 && s1 >= s5) {
            v5 = v3;
        } else {
            double v2 = (v1 + v3) / 2;
            double v4 = (v3 + v5) / 2;
            double s2 = smooth(v2, d);
            double s4 = smooth(v4, d);
            if (s4 >= s3 && s4 >= s5) {
                v1 = v3;
                v3 = v4;
            } else if (s2 >= s3 && s2 >= s1) {
                v5 = v3;
                v3 = v2;
            } else if (s3 >= s2 && s3 >= s4) {
                v1 = v2;
                v5 = v4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Já para achar o termo `a` com base na `soma` e no `d`, não há forma de se inverter a fórmula do `smooth` diretamente, então precisamos procurar o valor correspondente de forma iterativa:

```
private static boolean ordered(double a, double b, double c) {
    return (a <= b && b <= c) || (c <= b && b <= a);
}

public static double smoothRatio(double total, double... d) {
    double minA = 0.0;
    double maxA = bestSmooth(d);
    double smoothMin = smooth(minA, d);
    double smoothMax = smooth(maxA, d);
    if (!ordered(smoothMin, total, smoothMax)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    while (true) {
        if (total == smoothMin) return minA;
        if (total == smoothMax) return maxA;
        double mid = minA + (maxA - minA) / 2;
        if (mid == minA) return minA;
        if (mid == maxA) return maxA;
        double smoothMid = smooth(mid, d);
        if (ordered(smoothMid, total, smoothMax)) {
            minA = mid;
            smoothMin = smoothMid;
        } else if (ordered(smoothMid, total, smoothMin)) {
            maxA = mid;
            smoothMax = smoothMid;
        }
    }
}
```

Realizei um teste:

```
System.out.println(smoothRatio(7.078253125000002, 10, 40, 50, 20, 35));
```

E tive essa resposta:

```
0.05
```

Exemplos completos de testes (os três últimos são os da figura):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    testar(0.05, 10, 40, 50, 20, 35);
    testar(0.34, 22, 18);
    testar(0.25, 260, 350, 430, 280, 640, 650, 240, 430, 320, 585, 385, 450, 760, 690, 400);
    testar(null, 128, 180, 96, 108, 130, 150, 165, 139, 140, 165, 290, 190, 210, 240, 235);
    testar(null, 36, 48, 26, 31, 57, 42, 26, 23, 18, 25, 18, 36, 41, 18, 22);
}

private static void testar(Double a, double... d) {
    System.out.println("Valores: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(d));
    if (a != null) {
        double r = smooth(a, d);
        System.out.println("Taxa: " + a + " - resultado: " + r);
        double b = smoothRatio(r, d);
        System.out.println("Taxa (prova real): " + b);
    }
    double p = bestSmooth(d);
    System.out.println("Melhor taxa: " + p + " - resultado: " + smooth(p, d));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
Valores: [10.0, 40.0, 50.0, 20.0, 35.0]
Taxa: 0.05 - resultado: 7.078253125000002
Taxa (prova real): 0.05
Melhor taxa: 1.0 - resultado: 35.0

Valores: [22.0, 18.0]
Taxa: 0.34 - resultado: 11.056799999999999
Taxa (prova real): 0.33999999999999997
Melhor taxa: 0.9090909212827682 - resultado: 18.18181818181818

Valores: [260.0, 350.0, 430.0, 280.0, 640.0, 650.0, 240.0, 430.0, 320.0, 585.0, 385.0, 450.0, 760.0, 690.0, 400.0]
Taxa: 0.25 - resultado: 514.275442045182
Taxa (prova real): 0.24999999999999967
Melhor taxa: 0.3844731971623787 - resultado: 529.8357007856109

Valores: [128.0, 180.0, 96.0, 108.0, 130.0, 150.0, 165.0, 139.0, 140.0, 165.0, 290.0, 190.0, 210.0, 240.0, 235.0]
Melhor taxa: 0.9200836578384042 - resultado: 235.20144008802336

Valores: [36.0, 48.0, 26.0, 31.0, 57.0, 42.0, 26.0, 23.0, 18.0, 25.0, 18.0, 36.0, 41.0, 18.0, 22.0]
Melhor taxa: 0.21615071594715118 - resultado: 26.222890515272397
```

Nesses três últimos exemplos (tal como na figura), o primeiro deles (linha 3 da planilha, marcada com C) dá como resposta 514.275442045182 (que é o mesmo valor das células Q3-S3, se arredondado) usando uma taxa de 0.25 (célula U3). Se você usasse uma taxa ideal de 0.3844731971623787, a resposta seria o máximo possível para esses dados: 529.8357007856109

Para os demais exemplos, você não tem um valor de `a`. Diferentes valores de `a` produzirão diferentes resultados. Provavelmente o valor de `a` que mais interessa é aquele que produz o melhor resultado, o que é calculado por meio da função `bestSmooth`. Assim sendo, no caso da sua linha 5 da planilha (marcada com B), o melhor resultado possível é 235.20144008802336 a uma taxa ideal de 0.9200836578384042. No caso da sua linha 7 da planilha (marcada com A), o melhor resultado possível é 26.222890515272397 a uma taxa ideal de 0.21615071594715118.

Na vida real, nem sempre o melhor resultado ou a taxa ideal é alcançável, mas quanto mais a taxa real se aproximar da taxa ideal fornecida pela função `bestSmooth`, maior será o valor previsto.

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/dM2Tcz)

Comment: é por aí mesmo mas a potencia seria um i que incrementa. e no caso eu gostaria de calcular o alfa vou fazer as modificações para ver se chego lá.

Comment: Eu já tenho no caso o valor da soma que no exemplo é 22. como eu poderia calcular o a?

Comment: @user2509556 Você quer também uma outra fórmula onde com base no `d` e na soma, você encontre o `a`?

Comment: Quanto a variável potência, o negócio é que ela começa com o valor `1`, depois vai ser `(1 - a)`, depois `(1 - a)^2`, depois `(1 - a)^3`...

Comment: isso mesmo se puder me ajudar ... agradeço

Comment: @user2509556 Editei a resposta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58475/discussion-between-user2509556-and-victor-stafusa).

Comment: na realidade o que eu quero é calcular o alfa ou seja a variável "a" fiz um teste com o melhor alfa (0.34) e duas quantidade de vendas retiradas da planilha no caso o mês de junho com 22 e maio com 18.  

System.out.println(smooth(0.34, 22,18)); = 11.056799999999999
System.out.println(smoothRatio(11.056799999999999, 22,18)); = 0.09933183964086101

mesmo assim não deu. Acho que a formula não é esssa . Estamos passando o a como parametro e é ele que quero calcular.

Comment: @user2509556 Para mim, `smoothRatio(11.056799999999999, 22, 18)` deu `0.33999999999999997`.

Comment: Ah, uma outra coisa, você prefere os elementos `d` ordenados em ordem cronológica ou cronológica inversa? Porque eu imaginaria maio = 22 e junho = 18, e não o contrário.

Comment: é blz. o calculo está correto mesmo. mas de onde eu tiraria este somatório ? a principio eu só tenho d e os elementos são recebidos como parâmetros na forma inversa na figura [https://snag.gy/DGKr80.jpg] pode se ver  os meses jun, mai, abr, mar,... de forma descescente para o produto A B e C

Comment: @user2509556 o `a` é o que está na sua célula U3. O `d` é o que está nas células B3-P3 **na ordem** (observe que o `for` do `smooth` já está de trás para frente). Assim sendo, se você tem o `a` e os valores de `d`, basta chamar o `smooth`. No exemplo da linha C dessa sua figura, `smooth(0.25, 260, 350, 430, 280, 640, 650, 240, 430, 320, 585, 385, 450, 760, 690, 400)` deu como resultado 514.275442045182, que é o que está no Q3 (depois de arredondar). O processo inverso é para achar o U3 tendo-se o Q3 e os valores de `d`.

Comment: sim você está certo num ponto mas o a é um valor que eu quero calcular apesar de estar no excel, através dessa formula mesmo smooth, o que ocorre é que não consegui ver uma formula ainda para calculá-lo a = resultado

Comment: @user2509556 Editei a resposta de novo. Acho que o que você quer é o `bestSmooth`.

Comment: Como pode ser ver quanto mais se vende(valores de entrada - quantidade) , maior o alfa.Utilizei um exemplo com os  meses de janeiro a maio para calcular o de junho que no caso é 22.

    
     Obtive os seguintes valores Melhor taxa: 0.498 - resultado: 26 posso considerar 26 ao invés de 22 pela variação entre o real e o previsto. Como a venda é imprevisível o que quero é ter o previsível mais próximo do real o possível.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda seu cálculo foi ótimo.