# Erro ao popular array com Double

Tags: java, jpa

Preciso colocar em um `array` de `double` os dados do campo quantidade que vem do banco de dados. Ao fazer isto com o seguinte código:

```
static List<Historico> listaComCincoUltimosMeses = new ArrayList<Historico>
 ();
static double[] arrayinvertidoComUltimosCincoMeses = new double[listaComCincoUltimosMeses.size()];


  int k = 0;
  for (Historico hist : listaComCincoUltimosMeses) {                
     System.out.println(hist.getMesesHistoricos() == null ? "Erro" : 
        hist.getMesesHistoricos());

     System.out.println(hist.getQuantidade());
     arrayinvertidoComUltimosCincoMeses[k] = hist.getQuantidade();
     System.out.println(arrayinvertidoComUltimosCincoMeses.length);             
     System.out.println("Array"+ arrayinvertidoComUltimosCincoMeses[k]);
     k++;
}
```

recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Alguém sabe o porquê?

Eu quero colocar em um array de double porque recebo o array como entrada em uma função.

```
public static double fatorAmortecimentoExponencial(double... d) {
...
}
```

Comment: seu array tá instanciado e tem essa posição?

Comment: Onde e como está declarado o `arrayinvertidoComUltimosCincoMeses`?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (não é duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203324/132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vejamos isso:

```
static List<Historico> listaComCincoUltimosMeses = new ArrayList<Historico>
 ();
static double[] arrayinvertidoComUltimosCincoMeses = new double[listaComCincoUltimosMeses.size()];
```

Primeiro é criado uma `ArrayList` vazia, então `listaComCincoUltimosMeses.size()` será zero. Logo, você vai criar um array vazio com zero elementos. Tentar acessar-se qualquer posição de um array com zero elementos causa um `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Considerando que o que você está fazendo tem relação com [essa outra pergunta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203324/132), eu acho que o mais fácil para você seria fazer assim:

```
static List<Historico> listaComCincoUltimosMeses = new ArrayList<>();

// ...    

List<Double> ultimosCincoMeses = listaComCincoUltimosMeses.stream().map(Historico::getQuantidade).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.reverse(ultimosCincoMeses);
```

E então, você troca o método `fatorAmortecimentoExponencial(double... d)` para ser um `fatorAmortecimentoExponencial(List<Double> d)`.

Além disso, se você está usando o método [dessa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/203326/132) que itera a lista/array de trás para frente, mas você está invertendo ela para dar como entrada, vale a pena cogitar se o melhor não é fazer a lista/array ser iterada na ordem direta para que você não precise passá-la invertida.

Caso você queira passar a lista como array mesmo, você já sabe que o tamanho do array é 5:

```
static List<Historico> listaComCincoUltimosMeses = new ArrayList<>();

// ...

double[] array = new double[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    array[4 - i] = listaComCincoUltimosMeses.get(i).getQuantidade();
}
```

Esse índice `[4 - i]` deixa o array resultante em ordem inversa. Para ficar em ordem direta, você usaria simplesmente `[i]`.

Comment: A sua resposta me ajudou porque pude intanciar o meu array depois então ele não ficou com zero.

Answer (score 1):

Faltam mais detalhes na pergunta, mas acredito que, mesmo que tenha intanciado esse array, só deve existir a instância mesmo e nenhum índice para referenciar:
No caso de lista, você pode usar:

```
arrayinvertidoComUltimosCincoMeses.add(k, hist.getQuantidade())
```

Para o array, certifique-se que em sua instância esteja definida a quantidade de posições:

```
double[] arrayinvertidoComUltimosCincoMeses = new double[liataComCincoUltimosMeses.size()];
```

Você deve atribuir o tamanho do array só depois que sua listaComCincoUltimosMeses estiver populada, caso contrário, ela terá 0 posições, por isso  o retorno da falha.

Comment: Isso é um array, não um `List`.

Comment: Obrigada a atenção e sutileza. (=

Comment: instanciei sim as duas

Comment: Adiciona ao post, por gentileza?

Comment: Adicionei um comentário no final. Logo que tu instancia a lista, ela tem 0 posições, e é esse tamanho que tu tá atribuindo ao array. Atribua valores a lista primeiro, e depois defina o tamanho do array através do size da lista.